# Setting variable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a graphical interface for updating database entries using angular.js. My current strategy is to create a form for each entry that is viewable using  ng-hide. I'm currently struggling with accessing the information entered into the form.

The current code is as follows:

admin-edit.html:

```
<div ng-app= "routerApp" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat = 'question in multChoice' class = 'question' required>
                <div class = 'col-md-12'>
                    <label>Title: {{question.title}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>Type: {{question.type}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>Key: {{question.key}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>Options:</label>
                    <br>
                    <div ng-repeat = 'option in question.options' class = 'likert'>
                        <input type = 'radio' name = '{{question._id}}' value = '{{option.value}}' ng-model = 'question.userChoice'> {{option.text}}</input>

                    </div>
                </div>
        <button ng-click = 'edit = !edit; currentQuestion = question'>Edit</button>
        <div ng-show = 'edit'>
            <br>
                <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'title' >Title</input>
                <br>
                <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'type'>Type</input>
                <br>
                <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'key'>Key</input>
                <br>
                <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'op1'>Option 1</input>
                <br>
                <input type = 'text' ng-model = 'op2'>Option 2</input>
                <button ng-click = 'editQuestion(); edit = false'>Submit</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

relevant bits of formCtrl:

```
$scope.currentQuestion;
$scope.question;
$scope.title;
$scope.key;
$scope.type;

$scope.editQuestion = function(){
            console.log($scope.currentQuestion);
            if($scope.title == '' || !$scope.title){
                $scope.title = $scope.currentQuestion.title;
            }

            if($scope.key == '' || !$scope.key){
                $scope.key = $scope.currentQuestion.key;
            }

            if ($scope.type == '' || !$scope.type){
                $scope.type = $scope.currentQuestion.type;
            }

            $scope.question.title =$scope.title;
            $scope.question.key = $scope.key;
            $scope.question.type = $scope.type;

            questions.update($scope.question);
        }
```

Currently $scope.currentQuestion appears to never get assigned; it is undefined. How do I go about setting currentQuestion in its child scope?

Comment: make a online demo with your code to see what is happening

Comment: The common practice here is adding a jsfiddle/plunker with a demo code, reduced to the bare minimum that illustrates the problem. Also the question is unclear - what exactly is the problem - do you succeed in displaying the data and the problem is the editing? or something else

Comment: Also, notice that edit isn't on the $scope, at least not in the part you showed.

Comment: @alonisser When edit is clicked, editQuestion function is called and she is expecting  console.log($scope.currentQuestion) print the object but its staying undefined.

Comment: edit isn't relevant to the question. The difficulty is the assignment of current question. It's more of a conceptual question than anything else: how do you assign a variable in ng-repeat scope and access it in rootscope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am oversimplifying things, but I believe initializing $scope.currentQuestion will fix your problem, as in:

```
$scope.currentQuestion = {} ; // or load it from somewhere??
```

Comment: yes because `ng-repeat` creates a child scope and the undefined variable won't have inheritance and is currently only being set on child scopes , not on controller scope. Also better to have function set it in scope

Comment: it creates an empty object but does not help with assignment. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Carriemf need a function to set it on controller scope, you are only setting it on child scope and changing refrence breaks binding to parent

Comment: @charlietfl that is to say that a simple assignment (`currentQuestion = question`) does not work and that I need to have a function that returns question (i.e. `currentQuestion = setQuestion(question) ---> currentQuestion === question`)

Comment: yes...then the child scopes will pick it up in the digest. If you use object model in controller instead of assigning variables directly to $scope this gets much simpler...the whole model object will be inherited

Comment: @charlietfl, that worked well. The one change i made was assigning `$scope.currentQuestion` inside `setQuestion(question)` instead of returning `question` as was implied in my last comment.

Comment: @Carriemf yeah....I wasn't following the return part. Important lesson here about child scopes and conversely thinking object before primitive inside scope